# Making background jobs with Node/ES6

Tags: node.js

I would like to sort things such as sending notification emails out into the far-backend and write a couple of job classes. Like:

```
import JobBase from "some library...";
class SendEMails extends JobBase {
  // ...
}
```

Now, I did see a couple of Redis-backed job/task queues for Node, but appearently, they all just seem to operate on a single queue in Redis...which is kind of surprising, knowing that ES6 is around since a while now.

What would be a good method of defining job classes and running them when a job is queued - and having that organized in classes?

I really don't want to re-invent the wheel and write my own implementation... :)

Comment: Since it appears that you don't want to write your own implementation, that sounds like you're asking for 3rd party solutions here.  That would make the question off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: @jfriend00 Then I might close it. Can you recommend a good place to ask for such recommendations, though?

Comment: I'm not well versed in the other stacks, but perhaps this: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.  But, please read the posting rules there first to make sure you present the question in an on-topic way.